# AWS Lambda - Connect to MongoLab DB in same AWS region

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mlab

Trying out AWS Lambdas and trying to connect from one back to a MongoLab db hosted in the same AWS region:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    console.log("Connecting to Mongo");

    mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@dsxxxx-a0.mlab.com:xxxx,xxxx-a1.mlab.com:xxxx/xxxxxx?replicaSet=rs-xxxxx', function(err, db) {
        console.log("Connected to mongo");

        var col = db.collection('tasks');

        col.find({ }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('err > ' + err);
                throw err;
            }

            console.log('docs.length > ' + docs.length);

            docs.forEach(function(x) {
                console.log(x._id);
            });
        
            db.close();
            console.log("Done");
            context.done(null, "finished");
        });    
    });
};
```

I get the following log from Cloudwatch so I know I'm calling the Lambda and trying to connect to the db, but it never returns from the connection attempt and times out after 3 seconds:

> 2016-03-01T11:08:33.546Z ... **Loading function**
>
> START RequestId: Version: ... $LATEST
>
> 2016-03-01T11:08:33.548Z ... **Connecting to Mongo**
>
> END RequestId: ...
>
> REPORT RequestId: ... Duration: 3000.08 ms
>
> Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB  Max Memory Used: 35 MB
>
> 2016-03-01T11:08:36.547Z ... **Task timed out after 3.00 seconds**

The connection uri tests fine as is from 3T MongoChef so I know it's good, but are there any security or firewall settings somewhere (*say from IAM*) I need to set up or am I otherwise just missing something obvious?

Comment: Try setting a larger timeout on your lambda function to avoid the Lambda timeout. Then make sure your callback fn is handling (logging) the `err` object properly to report any connection errors you may be getting.

Comment: Matt, thanks, I'll give that a try later today when I can get back to it (you get a thumbs up from the MongoLab folks for this answer as well). My concern, though, is that if it takes that long to spin up a connection and the lambdas are torn down between calls that it's going to be a serious performance problem.

Comment: Looks more like security group settings. What is the inbound setting of the security group?

Comment: It was what Matt thought, it takes slightly more than 3 seconds to connect so bumping the lambda timeout did the trick. If there's no way around that and no way to lock the lambda down or somehow cache a live connection then AWS Lambdas aren't particularly useful in this scenario. I still have a hard time believing that and will check around some more to see if there is a better way to employ them or to interact with external services.